# sublime text - jsprettier: Unable to undestand this error why its showing

Tags: javascript, sublimetext, jsprettier

I am see this error from Jsprettier

```
------------------
 JsPrettier ERROR 
------------------

Prettier reported the following output:


[error] src/views/...: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (46:9)
[error]   44 |  currentTimezone = moment.tz.guess();
[error]   45 |
[error] > 46 |   const TimeZone = () => {
[error]      |         ^
[error]   47 |
[error]   48 |     return (
[error]   49 |       <div>
```

[image]